# What is wrong with this code? I am trying to make a program that computes tax and tips and ran into this problem

Tags: java

I feel like I am missing some form of conversion. I am still new to Java so I don't know much about it. Please help.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String mealCharge;
    double tax;
    double tip;
    double total;
    

    tax = mealCharge * 0.0625; //food tax is 6.25%
    tip = mealCharge * 0.15; //tip is 15%
    total = mealCharge + tax + tip;

    mealCharge = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the charge for the meal.");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total will be $" + total ".");

    
}
```

}

Comment: `mealCharge` is a String. It can hold values like "Dog", "Cat", "Agony" - In your case it is declared but not initialized.  What do you think it should be? Maybe "Cat"?  So "Cat" times 0.625 is like a cat without legs?  IDK.

Comment: On a side note from what others have said, you should use BigDecimal when working with Monetary values as this will also give control over set precision. Using BigDecimal::add, BigDecimal::subtract, BigDecimal::divide etc. for arithmatic instead of + - / *

Comment: Another possibility would be to use and `int` or `long` to represent the amount in cents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `mealCharge` is a `String` data type. But you can't use `String` type in the calculations. You need to convert `mealCharge` to the double/int/float/large/short data type. I assume, you need it to be a double type.

So, what I did I create a new variable for user input `String mealChargeInput` and new variable `double mealCharge;`. And then I convertend string to double by using `Integer.parseInt()` method.

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String mealChargeInput; //Create a different name for "mealCharge" string
    double mealCharge;
    double tax;
    double tip;
    double total;

    mealChargeInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the charge for the meal.");
    System.out.println(mealChargeInput.getClass().getSimpleName());
    mealCharge =  Double.parseDouble(mealChargeInput); // Convert string value of "mealChargeInput" to the double value and assign it to a new double variable

    tax = mealCharge * 0.0625; //food tax is 6.25%
    tip = mealCharge * 0.15; //tip is 15%
    total = mealCharge + tax + tip;


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total will be $" + total +"."); //Missing "+" operator;


}
```

Is it what you need?

Comment: Yes, this is what I've been looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

You cant multiply a string (ie, mealCharge) with Double(ie, tip/tax). Change your datatype of the mealCharge to Double and you are good to go.

Answer (score -2):

From your code, I believe you didn't initialized it with a valued. It will result in error as there is no value before trying to calculate.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
double mealCharge;
double tax;
double tip;
double total;

mealCharge = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the charge for the meal."));

tax = mealCharge * 0.0625; //food tax is 6.25%
tip = mealCharge * 0.15; //tip is 15%
total = mealCharge + tax + tip;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total will be $" + total + ".");
```

}